# JQuery Waypoint function not reseting after resize

Tags: jquery, resize, jquery-waypoints

I've looked around extensively on StackOverflow for an answer to this and can't find anything that fixes my issue.

Basically, I've got a waypoint function that fires in the header. It's supposed to fire in two different manners, depending on the window width. Loading the script within the width parameters (one is less than 750 pixels, the other is greater than 750 pixels) results in the expected behaviour.

If a user resizes the screen, however, going from say 800 pixels to 400 pixels, the function from 800 pixels still runs. This is despite the function being bound to a resize event.

I have a feeling I need to refresh the function entirely on a resize, but I am unsure how to achieve this.

Below is my code. I've tried running the mobileView and the tabletView in the same function, but always to get the same result.

```
var _w = Math.max( $(window).width(), $(window).height() );
    var mobileView = (_w <= 750);
    var largeView = (_w >= 751);    

    var header_cta = $(".header_cta");
    var midbar = $(".midbar");
    var header_container = $(".header");

    var top_spacing = 0;
    var waypoint_offset = 1;

    //var scrollbar = (window.innerWidth-$(window).width());

    var header_waypoint_handler = new Waypoint({            

        element: document.getElementById('header_waypoint'),
        handler: function(direction) {                                  

            function large_header_waypoint() {
                if (largeView) {
                    if (direction === 'down') {
                        header_container.css({ 'height':midbar.outerHeight() });        
                        midbar.stop().addClass("stick").css("top",-midbar.outerHeight()).animate({"top":top_spacing});
                    }
                    if (direction === 'up') {
                        header_container.css({ 'height':'auto' });
                        midbar.removeClass("stick").css("top",midbar.outerHeight()+waypoint_offset).animate({"top":""});

                    }

                }
            }

            function mobile_header_waypoint() {
                if (mobileView) {

                    if (direction === 'down') {
                      $('div.header_hamburger_menu').addClass('stick');
                      header_container.css({ 'height':header_cta.outerHeight() });      
                      header_cta.stop().addClass("stick").css("top",-header_cta.outerHeight()).animate({"top":top_spacing});
                    }
                    if (direction === 'up') {
                      $('div.header_hamburger_menu').removeClass('stick');
                      header_container.css({ 'height':'auto' });
                      header_cta.removeClass("stick").css("top",header_cta.outerHeight()+waypoint_offset).animate({"top":""});
                    }
                }
            }

            $(window).resize(function() {
                large_header_waypoint();
                mobile_header_waypoint();
            }).resize();
        },
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried `Waypoint.refreshAll();`

Comment: Have tried without any luck. Have placed that with the resize event, and within the functions too. I have a feeling I have been using it incorrectly, however.

Comment: I remember having similar problems with a sticky header. I end up switching to [ScrollMagic](http://scrollmagic.io/) because it's automatically responsive. No need to refresh

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party here but I ran into a similar problem recently implementing Waypoints 4.0.0 (no-framework) on a horizontally scrolling site.

For the record the documentation states a refresh is called on window resize:

> automatically when the window is resized, so it only needs to be called manually when layout changes happen outside of a resize.

For whatever reason this doesn't appear to be happening as expected so I worked around it by leveraging an old debouncing function (John Hann - http://unscriptable.com/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/) in combination with `Waypoint.refreshAll();`.

Debounce Function:

```
// debouncing function from John Hann
(function($,sr){
    var debounce = function (func, threshold, execAsap) {
        var timeout;
        return function debounced () {
            var obj = this, args = arguments;
            function delayed () {
                if (!execAsap)
                    func.apply(obj, args);
                timeout = null;
            };
            if (timeout)
                clearTimeout(timeout);
            else if (execAsap)
                func.apply(obj, args);
            timeout = setTimeout(delayed, threshold || 100);
        };
    }
    // smartresize 
    jQuery.fn[sr] = function(fn){
        return fn ? this.bind('resize', debounce(fn)) : this.trigger(sr);
    };
})(jQuery,'smartresize');
```

Call Debounce with Waypoints:

```
// Refresh Waypoints after browser resize:
$(window).smartresize(function(){
    Waypoint.refreshAll();
});
```